# Putting FLV video on website - How to add a static image before it plays

Tags: flash, video, flv, dreamweaver

I am trying to put an FLV video on a website.

I tried using Dreamweaver CS3 (Insert - Media - Flash Video), it works great except for 2 problems:

1. The video starts black (How do you show an image prior to playing the video?)
2. The browser starts downloading the whole movie even before the play button is clicked (I want the video to be downloaded only after the user clicks on Play)

Anyone has a solution for this? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if Dreamweaver's FLV player supports this.  However, you can use a different player such as [JW FLV Media Player](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/), which supports the features you ask for.

Comment: Hi strager, thank you! It works. But I got a little arrow icon on the top left (if clicked it shows the code to share). How do you get rid of it? Thanks!

Comment: I got it, don't tick include Viral when downloading. Thank you for your other comments as well

Answer (score 1):

just click on preview in the compontent inspector of flash and it will show up when you embed in your html code.

Answer (score 1):

Add your image to the first 5 frames of the video.  I usually take a snapshot from somewhere in the video but any image that you want to replace the black screen will do fine.

Answer (score 0):

What the browser may or may not do with regards to precaching is not defined and thus cannot really be controlled.  If you really think you know better than the browser, insert the tag using JavaScript after the video is supposed to start to load.

Given the behaviour you want, that's likely best.  Put an <img/> tag in the page with an ID, then when you want to play the video, have javascript replace the <img/> with the <object></object>

Comment: The flash video does not have the FLV embedded in it.  The flash video loads the FLV itself, not the browser.

Comment: On the img/object swap, <object> can be used to display an image.  (Not sure about browser support, though.)  A few attribute changes can solve the problem as well.

Comment: While <object> can display an image, it's just as easy to swap the tags out, and this improves browser support.

I wasn't aware that Dreamwever used an SWF to embed an FLV. That seems like silly overkill.

Comment: @singpolyma, I would assume it would.  I don't think FLV files are natively playable by most computer setups without the aid of Flash.

Answer (score 0):

maybe a simple javascript function would work best here, something like:

```
<div id="videodiv" style="width:300px; height:300px;"
      onclick="this.innerHTML='whatever HTML dreamweaver gives you'">
  <img src="yourimage">
</div>
```

Comment: Weird escaping would need to occur because 'whatever HTML dreamweaver gives him' probably includes ", ', <, and >.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit your flash video player to insert an image before your flv file and make it not auto load on web page opening.

The [Moyea Web Player](http://www.playerdiy.com/) can solve these two problems. It enables you to add an image at any point to the FLV movie, see the screenshot of this feature:

[image: add image screen]

And you can make the FLV not auto load when the web page opens by unchecking "Auto load":

[image: auto load checkbox]

Answer (score -1):

> In the properties area, simply click
>   'autoplay' and turn it off.

This is correct, maybe just not as complete as it could be - on the stage click your FLVPlayback component so that it is selected, then in the Component Inspector (open by pressing shift + F7) click "autoPlay" and select "false".