# How to edit existing video FLV with Linux Command or PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, css, flv, jwplayer

I'm trying to edit a video in flv which I add a background image and text in the video at a given time and give a specific position in the video.

For example: The image must be in the upper right of the video from second 10 to second 20 of the video. The text needs to go in the bottom of the video from the second 5 to second 9.

Then save the edited video on the server.

Is there a program in linux that can do this for command line? o Is there a special library for php that can do this?

I really need to know this. Use ffmpeg but not helped me what I wanted.

Note: I use JW Player for reproduce the video in flv.

---

**Update:**

I Use JW Player for custom the video. But only custom when the user play the video and only in this moment.

But, when I want to capture that video "edited" to generate a new one in flv format, the JW Player will not let me.

This is my code in HTML:

```
<div id="image-user" style="z-index: 1; display: none"><img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>images/imagen.png" alt="imagen_usuario"></img></div>

<div id="txt-user" style="z-index: 1; display: none">TEXT USER</div>
```

This is my Javascript:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jwplayer('container').setup({
        flashplayer: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>jwplayer/jwplayer.flash.swf",
        file: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>jwplayer/mario.flv",
        height: 261,
        width: 308,
        events: {
            onTime: function(event){
                if(event.position > 5 && event.position < 10){
                    $('div#image-user').css('display','block');
                    $('div#txt-user').css('display','block');
                }else{
                    $('div#image-user').css('display','none');
                    $('div#txt-user').css('display','none');
                }
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

My goal is to share this video released on facebook. ¿Can I share this player with all configuration on facebook wall as show above?

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/652975/putting-flv-video-on-website-how-to-add-a-static-image-before-it-plays?rq=1 ? apparantly the same program can probably do what you are wanting.

Comment: @cryptic OK.. I'll try with Moyea Web Player

Comment: Where in the marked answer for that question do they say to use Moyea?!? They use JW Player, read the **accepted** answer to the question.

Comment: I used the JW Player, but this only allows me to put an image at the beginning of the video and not save the edited video. What I want is to put an image and text in a given time and position in the video. Because, I create a new Video FLV edited.

Comment: I think you are better off using javascript. Basically when the video starts you start a javascript timer which after 10 seconds will display an image over the player window where you want, and after 20 seconds will remove the image. There is no need to edit the video. If you want to show advertising you would use this method, otherwise you would be stuck with an FLV video which has a fixed image, using javascript makes it dynamic so you can change it whenever.

Comment: OK.. I create 2 html elements. 1 div that contain the image that i want and other div that contain the text. Both have a z-index higher than JW-Player. 2 elements begin with `display:none`. Then i use the event `onTime` of JW Player that change this to `display:block`.
OK this work perfect. But i need to capture all this change and generate a video flv. Beacuse i need to share this.

Comment: Yes, and have JS overlay them at the appropriate time and then remove them after x-seconds. Make sure you compensate for a user pausing the video, so you need to check for those events. Search on `Google JW Player advertisement` there will be a lot on the topic.

Comment: So, with JW Player I can generate a FLV Video with the changes that I do. I posted the first part of this.

Comment: @cryptic can I share all this configuration on facebook wall?

Comment: Please delete your below post thats not how StackOverflow works. I have added the below to your above post as it should have been done, and also added/removed tags so other experts from other sections will know of the question.

Comment: @cryptic OK, I deleted it

Comment: Do you have an example of where the "JW Player will not let you" do this?

Also, in terms of posting to Facebook, here is some information - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/blog/19150/publish-your-videos-to-facebook-with-a-jw-player

Comment: @EthanLongTail the JW Player only can reproduce flv videos and attach other things with their API. But, the player can't compress all this thing and generate a new flv with this changes.

Now, the event ONTIME handle my HTML Elements for show on the video.
In this blog, i can't see if i share the video with the event and HTML elements that i want.

Comment: Correct, the JW Player does not actually convert/generate anything, it is simply a player which will player whatever file is fed into it.